# Proving roots of a polynomial are outside of a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for every positive real number R there exist an integer N such that, for all $n > N$, all roots of the polynomial $$1+\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{z^n}{n!}$$ are outside the circle $C(0,R)$

I came across this problem in a complex analysis book that I am trying to reason through and I am unsure how to begin the proof of a polynomial's root being outside of a circle.

Comment: Maybe you should use 1. Rouché's Theorem 2. the fact that this sequence of polynomials converges uniformly to $e^z$ on compact sets 3. $e^z$ has no zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $R>0$ and let $$M_R =\inf_{|z|\leq R} |e^z|$$ let $W_n (z) =\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{z^j}{j!}$ since $W_n (z) \to e^z $ uniformly on compact set $\{z: |z|\leq R\}$ there exists $n_0$ such that $|W_n (z) -e^z|\leq \frac{M_R}{4}$ for all $|z|\leq R$ and $n\geq n_0$ thus $$|W_n (z)|\geq |e^z| -|W_n (z) -e^z|\geq M_R -\frac{M_R}{4} =\frac{3M_R}{4}$$ for all $|z|\leq R$ and $n\geq n_0.$